# How to get the exponent "x" (2 to the power of "x") without using Math.log in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, bit-manipulation

I have this so far (which is all bitwise, not using `Math` functions):

```
function nextPowerOf2(n) {  
  if (n && !(n & (n - 1))) {
    return n
  }

  let p = 1
  while (p < n) {
    p <<= 1
  }
  
  return p  
}
```

To get the exponent though, I have to do this:

```
const exp = Math.log2(nextPowerOf2(val))
```

Is there any way to do this without `Math.log`, using more primitive operations? Which way is better performing?

Comment: so like `2**x`?

Comment: I want to get `x`, how do you get x?

Comment: nevermind ... I think you are over complicating it to be honest ... let me check what your code does to see if my suspicions are correct

Comment: `Math.ceil(Math.log2(val))`?

Comment: I would like to see how it's done using only bitwise operators if at all possible.

Comment: oh ... right ...wouldn't you just count the number of shift rights of the result of nextPowerOf2 until you get 0? i.e. the inverse of what you already have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can count number of bits in a number - that will be log2(nextPowerOf2):

```js
const log2ofNextPowerOf2 = (x) => {
  if (!x) return 0;
  let c = 0, b = 0;
  while (x > 0) {
    c++; b += x & 1;
    x = x >> 1;
  }
  return b == 1 ? c - 1 : c;
}

// test it:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 100].forEach(n => console.log(n, '=>', log2ofNextPowerOf2(n)));
```

Compare this to your original function:

```js
function nextPowerOf2(n) {
  if (n && !(n & (n - 1))) {
    return n
  }
  let p = 1
  while (p < n) {
    p <<= 1
  }

  return p
}

// test it:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 100].forEach(n => console.log(n, '=>', Math.log2(nextPowerOf2(n))));
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience Math.log2 is pretty performant, especially when compared to other options using bitwise and even lookup tables.

If you would like to see how it could be done with bitwise here is a great resource: [http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog](http://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog)

Here is an example adapted for JS from C++ (be careful of numbers past `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`) which is ~59% slower

```js
function log2(v) {
    let b = [0x2, 0xC, 0xF0, 0xFF00, 0xFFFF0000, 0xFFFFFFFF00000000];
    let S = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32];
    let i;

    let r = 0;
    for (i = 5; i >= 0; i--){
        if (v & b[i]) {
            v >>= S[i];
            r |= S[i];
        } 
    }

    return r;
}

log2(nextPowerOf2(348209348));
```